# Probability: random elevator stops

Tags: probability

I have a elevator probability problem but with a twist (instead of people exiting the elevator, it is the elevator stopping on each level). Require some help understanding and completing the probability questions.

**Problem:**

4 people go into the elevator of a 5-storey shophouse. Assume that each of them exits the building uniformly at random at any of the 5 levels and independently of each other. N is the random variable which is the total number of elevator stops.

1. Describe the sample space for this random process.

**Answer:** {1,2,3,4,5}

**Understanding:** Sample space represents all the possible outcomes of the random event. Hence, the elevator can only stop at these 5 floors. Just like throwing a die and randomly getting a number, the sample space for that is {1,2,3,4,5,6}.

2. Let $X_i$ be the random variable that equals to 1 if the elevator stops at floor i and 0, otherwise. Find the probability that the elevator stops at both floors $a$ and $b$ for $a$, $b$ $\in$ {1,2,3,4,5}. Find $EX_aX_b$.

**Question:** Do they mean the elevator stop at two consecutive floors or two different floors? Can a and b be the same, a smaller than b and vice versa?

3. Prove the independence of $EX_1X_2$.
4. Calculate $EN^2$ (represented as ($X_1 + ...+ X_5)^2 = \sum_{(i,j)}  X_aX_b$ where the sum is over all ordered pairs (a,b) of numbers from {1,2,3,4,5} and the linearity of expectation. Find the variance of N.
5. Determine the distribution of N. That is, determine the probabilities of events N = i. Compute $EN and EN^2$ directly by using the laws of expectation.

I got stuck from question 2 onwards with thinking of the possible ways that this can be done. It would be superb if someone can shed some light on them. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)**

Your answer only gives the set of values that can be taken by $N$ as outcomes. That is not enough in this situation.

You could go for $\Omega=\{0,1\}^5$ where e.g. $\omega=(1,0,0,1,0)$ is the outcome that the elevator stops on the floors $1$ and $4$.

Then for $i\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ we prescribe random variable $X_i:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ by $\omega=(\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\omega_4,\omega_5,)\mapsto\omega_i$.

Then the event "the elevator stops at floor $i$" can be recognized as the event $\{X_i=1\}$.

**2)**

I would rather avoid $a,b$ and choose for $i,j$ instead. Note that $X_iX_j=1$ if and only if the elevator stops at floor $i$ and stops at floor $j$. This with $\mathbb EX_iX_j=P(X_iX_j=1)$ because $X_iX_j$ only takes values in $\{0,1\}$.

If $i=j$ then $X_iX_j=X_i^2=X_i$ so in that case we must find $P(X_i=1)$.

This can be done by:$$P(X_i=1)=1-P(X_i=0)=1-\left(\frac45\right)^4$$

Observe here that $\{X_i=0\}$ is the event that all passengers exit on a floor different from $i$.

If $i\neq j$ then we go for calculation:$$P\left(X_{i}X_{j}=1\right)=P\left(X_{i}=1\wedge X_{j}=1\right)=1-P\left(X_{i}=0\vee X_{j}=0\right)=$$$$1-P\left(X_{i}=0\right)-P\left(X_{j}=0\right)+P\left(X_{i}=0\wedge X_{j}=0\right)=1-2\cdot\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{4}+\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{4}$$

**3)**

I don't know what is meant by "prove the independence of $\mathbb EX_1X_2$" since $\mathbb EX_1X_2$ is a real number. They might mean something like: "check that $\mathbb EX_iX_j$ is not depending on $(i,j)$ if $i\neq j$.

**4)**

$N^2=\sum_{i=1}^5\sum_{j=1}^5X_iX_j$ and this equality enables you to find an expression for $\mathbb EN^2$ by means of linearity of expectation and symmetry.

**5)**

Finding $P(N=i)$ for $i=1,2,3,4,5$ might turn out to be the hardest part of the question, but something must be left for you.

If you don't manage to do it yourself then please let me know.

---

**edit** (concerning determination of distribution of $N$).

Number the floors with $1,2,3,4,5$ using index variable $j$ for
them.

Number the persons with $1,2,3,4$ using index variable $i$ for them.

Let $Y_{i,j}=1$ if person $i$ leaves the elevator at floor $j$
and let $Y_{i,j}=0$ otherwise.

Then $Y_{j}:=\sum_{i=1}^{4}Y_{i,j}$ equalizes the number of persons
that leave the elevator at floor $j$.

Here $Y_{1,j},Y_{2,j},Y_{3,j},Y_{4,j}$ are iid and have Bernoulli
distribution with parameter $\frac{1}{5}$.

Consequently $Y_{j}$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n=4$
and $p=\frac{1}{5}$.

Next to that we have: $$\sum_{j=1}^{5}Y_{j}=4\tag1$$

$Y:=\left(Y_{1},Y_{2},Y_{3},Y_{4},Y_{5}\right)$ is a random vector where
$Y_{j}$ denotes the number of persons that leave the elevator at
floor $j$.

$Y$ has [$5$-nomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) with parameters $n=4$ and probabilities
$\left(p_{1},p_{2},p_{3},p_{4},p_{5}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5}\right)$.

This means that: $$P\left(Y=\left(r_{1},r_{2},r_{3},r_{4},r_{5}\right)\right)=5^{-4}\frac{4!}{r_{1}!r_{2}!r_{3}!r_{4}!r_{5}!}\tag2$$
for nonnegative integers $r_{1},\dots,r_{5}$ that satisfy $r_{1}+r_{2}+r_{3}+r_{4}+r_{5}=4$

We can define $N$ as the cardinality of the random set $S=\left\{ j\in\left\{ 1,2,3,4,5\right\} \mid Y_{j}>0\right\} $.

Based on $(1)$ we find:

- $N=1\iff\left\{ Y_{1},Y_{2},Y_{3},Y_{4},Y_{5}\right\} =\left\{ 4,0\right\} $
- $N=2\iff\left\{ Y_{1},Y_{2},Y_{3},Y_{4},Y_{5}\right\} =\left\{ 2,0\right\} \text{ or }\left\{ Y_{1},Y_{2},Y_{3},Y_{4},Y_{5}\right\} =\left\{ 3,1,0\right\} $
- $N=3\iff\left\{ Y_{1},Y_{2},Y_{3},Y_{4},Y_{5}\right\} =\left\{ 2,1,0\right\} $
- $N=4\iff\left\{ Y_{1},Y_{2},Y_{3},Y_{4},Y_{5}\right\} =\left\{ 1,0\right\} $

This enables you to find the distribution of $N$.

As an example let us find $P\left(N=3\right)$.

In order to get $\left\{ Y_{1},Y_{2},Y_{3},Y_{4},Y_{5}\right\} =\left\{ 2,1,0\right\} $
first observe on base of $(2)$ that: $$P\left(Y_{1}=2,Y_{2}=1,Y_{3}=1\right)=5^{-4}\frac{4!}{2!1!1!0!0!}=12\cdot5^{-4}$$

Then realize that $Y=(2,1,1,0,0)$ is just one of $5\binom{4}{2}=30$ possibilities to arrive
at $\left\{ Y_{1},Y_{2},Y_{3},Y_{4},Y_{5}\right\} =\left\{ 2,1,0\right\} $
so that finally we arrive at: $$P\left(N=3\right)=30\cdot12\cdot5^{-4}=360\cdot5^{-4}$$

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you got the calculation in (2) when i does not equal to j. Would like some explanation regarding this. Furthermore, shouldn't the index power 6 be 4 as there are 4 people in the elevator?

Comment: Trying to find the distribution but not sure what it means by N = i. I am confused as earlier in the question we have defined N as the total number of elevator stops. In (5), N is to be the each floor from 1 to 5? Please help.

Comment: In the calculation in (2) there was one small typo that is repaired now (a $i$ had to be changed into a $j$). There are 4 equalities there. Tell me which one is bothering. In your question I read explicitly that 6 persons are initially in the elevator  (not 4). I need clarity about that before I can handle the distribution of $N$. Chances are small that I can help today.

Comment: Apologies for the typo. It is a mistake on my part. I have edited the question to reflect 4 people instead of 6. I misread the question. Truly sorry about that.  If you could explain $1-P\left(X_{i}=0\right)-P\left(X_{j}=0\right)+P\left(X_{i}=0\wedge X_{j}=0\right)$ for the calculation in (2). Thanks again for your help.

Comment: In general $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$. Applying that for $A=\{X_i=0)$ and $B=\{X_j=0\}$ we find $P(X_i=0\vee X_j=0\}=P(X_i=0)+P(X_j=0)-P(X_i=0\wedge X_j=0\}$. Further $N=i$ stands for the event that on exactly $i$ distinct floors at least one passenger left the elevator.

Comment: Hi, I am unable to find the distribution of N, can you help me?

Comment: I have edited my answer and added how you can find the distribution of $N$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am working through this right now and am confused at this part $N=1\iff\left\{ Y_{1},Y_{2},Y_{3},Y_{4},Y_{5}\right\} =\left\{ 4,0\right\} $ right until before the example. Also for N=3, how did we arrive to 2,1,1 instead of 2,1,0?

Comment: $\{2,1,1,0,0\}=\{2,1,0\}$ because we are dealing with sets here (not tuples). A set is determined by its elements which are $2,1,0$ here and we do not have to denote the elements more than once. If this set is $\{4,0\}$ then it must that be that at least one of the $Y_j$ takes value $4$ and consequently the others take value $0$. That means that all persons stepped out on the same floor so that in that case $N=1$.

Comment: It might be that I did not explain properly in my former comment what you were asking for. Where exactly did we arrive at 2,1,1?

Comment: After working through the sum more deeply, I came to understand that {2,1,0} is the sample space of N=3. That means that all possible outcomes of N = 3 is either 2 persons,1, or no one coming out on that floor. 2,1,1 came to when you mentioned $P\left(Y_{1}=2,Y_{2}=1,Y_{3}=1\right)$ and that is just one of 30 possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify the events $X_a$ and $X_b$, but from the context I assume it is meant that
$$ X_a = 1\{\text{elevator stops at floor } a\}. $$
You have to find $\mathbb{E}X_aX_b$, which is equal to the probability that the elevator stops at both floor $a$ and $b$. In the question it is only stated that $a,b \in \{1,\dots,5\}$ but it is not specified that they can't be equal, meaning we should also answer the question in the event $a = b$. Moreover, it does not have to be the case that $a$ and $b$ are two consecutive floors, since in that case they would have stated that $a \in \{1,\dots,5\}$ and $b = a+1$. So you should just read this question as: given two floors, what is the probability that the elevator stops at these two floors (or, in case $a = b$: given this floor, what is the probability that the elevator stops at this floor).

As mentioned above, we have two different scenario's: $a$ and $b$ different floors or $a = b$ and we only consider one floor. I will now give a hint on answering the question for both scenario's:

$a = b$:
in the case $a = b$ we have to find $\mathbb{P}(\text{ elevator stops at floor a})$. Since the only way the elevator stops at this floor is if there are people exiting the elevator at this floor, we have that:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\text{elevator stops at floor a}) &= 
\mathbb{P}(\geq 1 \text{ people exit the elevator at floor a}) \\
&= 1 - \mathbb{P}(\text{no people exit at floor a}) 
\end{align*}
and we can compute this last probability, working with binomial random variables.

$a \neq b$:
in the case $a \neq b$ we have to find $\mathbb{P}(\text{ elevator stops at both floor a and b})$. A hint to find this probability is to use the rule: $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B) - \mathbb{P}(A \cup B)$ and use the results from the case $a = b$.